# Сбор данных с сайта

Tags: android

Привет всем,

хочу написать приложение, собирающее статьи из сайта определенной тематики. Например, из сайта хабр выдирать статьи категории "Разработка под Android". И планируется их сохранять в некотором списке. Со списками уже знаком. Подскажите куда копать для описанной выше задачи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Писать свой парсер на регулярках.

2) Ждать. Админы обещали API для подобных вещей.

Comment: А "регулярки" это что?

Comment: @Миха, регулярные выражения.

Answer (score 1):

В списках хранить ничего не нужно, для этого есть база данных, для парсинга есть библиотека jsoup
[оф сайт](http://jsoup.org/download)
[о ней на русском](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/library/jsoup.php)